# Remove all records from bound datatable, can't update?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, delete-row, bindingsource

I have a datatable inside a dataset that is populated from an SQL query. I want to hit a button and delete all the data inside the datatable.

I've tried many solutions and usually my data will clear out of my datagridview, but when I reload the form, the data is still there!

So I played around with different methods of updating so that the rows marked for deletion would then be removed upon updating. All methods would either not work, or throw an exception.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Try

        For Each dr As DataRow In DataSet.BT_Order.Rows
            dr.Delete()
        Next


        Me.Validate()
        Me.BT_OrderTableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.BT_OrderTableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet.BT_Order)
        MsgBox("updated")

    Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("failed")
    End Try
End Sub
```

I've also tried things such as....with an update after

```
while i < datarows blah blah
dataset.tables("mytable").rows.remove(i)
loop

Me.BT_OrderTableAdapter.Update(Me.DataSet.BT_Order)
```

I've tried different methods of removing/deleting/clearing, with different methods of updating/not updating, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]  Removing rows and deleting there are 2 different things blah blah blah

Comment: @Plutonix I appreciate the "blah"s, but I'm using both because I've tried seemingly everything. This is the first thing in VB that I haven't been able to figure out from StackOverflow and the like. Pretty frustrated.

Is there something specific I can do to change my question to make it better?

Comment: "data will clear out of my datagridview, but when I reload the form, the data is still there" -- Are you using a local db file (i.e. Access) and selected "copy file to your project" when you created the data source?  If so, check the properties of the file in via the Solution Explorer to make sure "Copy to output directory" is not set to "Copy Always".

Comment: can you post the code that generates the query and returns the data?  That would give us some clues.

Comment: [DataTable.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PrescottChartier the code that generates the data is a query that selects  "companyNo" and "OrderNo", and then the DGV displays it.


The SQL statement is just 

SELECT companyno and orderno from BT_Order

Comment: @TnTinMn Specifically which item's parameters are you referring to? 


I've looked at the DGV, the datatable, and the bindingsource for the table. Have not found anything referring to 'copy' or 'copyalways'.


Thanks for the reply!

Comment: My comment was conditioned on  "If you are using a local db file", like a MS Access Database. It is a common issue that people believe their code is not updating the db, but what is happening on each debug run is that the modified db file is overwritten with the original file.  **If this applies to your project**, the db file should be listed in the Solution Explorer window (ex:  MyDbFile.mdb or MyDb.accdb).

Comment: @Andrew, is the database a local database or a Sql server, MySQL server or some other remote server?  If not TnTinMn's comment is very relevant.

Comment: @TnTinMn 

Figured it out! After 2 days of trying 20 combinations of methods of removing/clearing/deleting and updating......no primary key for the SQL statement!

Thanks much for your replys, I'm sure we would've gotten there today with your help!

Comment: @PrescottChartier  figured it out (above comment) Thanks much for your help, I'm sure we would've figured it out today regardless!

Comment: Kewl ... glad we were of some assistance.